# How do I convert this ffmpeg command to be used in ffmpy?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, image-processing, ffmpeg

I have a gif that I am taking apart frame by frame in order to write text onto it. I used ffmpeg to put the frames (saved as individual `.png` files) back together and it worked nicely. This is the code I used:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i newimg%d.png out.gif`

But now I want to use the python wrapper `ffmpy`. Following the docs, I tried a variety of things but I keep getting syntax errors.

Here is one instance of my efforts:

```
ff = ffmpy(FFmpeg(inputs = {ffmpeg -f image2 -i "newimg%d.png"}, outputs = {"gif_with_text.gif"}))
ff.run()
```

In this attempt, the syntax error points to the "2" in `image2`. Could someone help me out? Note - I'm new to python, let alone ffmpeg and ffmpy.

Comment: There are several problems in your code. First, `FFmpeg` is a function from module `ffmpy` and should be called as `ffmpy.FFmpeg`. Second, the parameter to the function must be a dictionary. Third, your inputs must be either one string or a list of strings; same for outputs.

Comment: @Dyz wait what does it mean for the "parameter to the function must be a dictionary"?

Comment: Oops, never mind about the second note. But here's an example of how to use the function: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpy/0.2.0

Comment: @DYZ got it, thanks!

Comment: @DYZ I tried the code exactly as in the example, but I get this error:`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` and then `FFExecutableNotFoundError("Executable '{0}' not found".format(self.executable))
ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found` --- any idea what causes this error? Thanks...

Comment: Please install ffmpeg.